# CakePHP Deprecated FactoryTrait?

Tags: php, cakephp

I got a new PC and is setting up my CakePHP project on it, but i get these errors:

> Deprecated: Return type of Cake\Chronos\Traits\FactoryTrait::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz = null) should either be compatible with DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(string $format, string $datetime, ?DateTimeZone $timezone = null): DateTimeImmutable|false, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laragon\www\bakeboss\vendor\cakephp\chronos\src\Traits\FactoryTrait.php on line 204

3 different types of those errors dealing with the FactoryTrait.

Now, the project works, so my first thought was just to de-activate the deprecated warnings, but i can't get that to work either? I tried setting this in the app file:

```
'Error' => [
    'errorLevel' => E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED,
    'exceptionRenderer' => 'Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer',
    'skipLog' => [],
    'log' => true,
    'trace' => true,
],
```

But still no luck..? any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the PHP version is the same as before.

Comment: that is the same (8.1) - i have a live version running on a server that doesn't show those deprecated warnings - only my localhost does

Comment: @J.B.J. try  updating composer `composer update`

Comment: The trait is not deprecated! The message says it's an issue with return types. Make sure you are using a supported PHP version and double-check your app code.

Comment: As the error message suggests, you could use the `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` annotation. This is just a notice not an error.